# Build singularity image file from a singularity-vagrant-box

Tags: vagrant, singularity-container

Everything is inside the title. I have a singularity vagrant box setup on my computing, and I'm looking for a way to generate a .sif (singularity image file) from it.

Do you know if that is possible ?

My vagrant-vm is on windows10.

Any advice or external link will be appreciated ^^

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to build a singularity image *based on* a vagrant VM, though you can use a vagrant VM to do the actual building.

*original answer:*

You can just `vagrant ssh` to the VM and use singularity normally. The [user guide docs](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/quick_start.html) are fairly comprehensive and searchable.

The [Singularity admin guide](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/admin-guide/installation.html#singularity-vagrant-box) has info specifically on using Singularity in Vagrant on a Windows host OS. It is not the first place I'd personally expect it to be, but it is there and should get you up and going anyway.

Comment: Yes, but now if i want to build a .sif file that correspond to my vm, I should build a .def first right ? My goal is not tu run my script using singularity on my VM, but to build a .sif from it. I already did the steps you send me the link

Comment: Ah, you want to build a singularity image OF the vagrant VM itself? Vagrant is just another container to run Singularity in. Building a SIF requires either a definition file, as you mention, or an existing container from a docker or singularity container repository

Comment: Ok, sad for me, btw ty for your help !